# PHP - Managing A Lot of Data Without Database

Tags: php, mysql, web-scraping

The Problem

I have an app that scrapes data and presents it to the user, directly, because of lack of disk space.

This data is very volatile, it can change within minutes. Much like the stock market.

Since the data changes so often, and it varies from user to user, it is useless to save it in a database.

The question

I need to sort the data presented to the user, compare it, link it etc. A lot of functions that a database provides. Yet I cannot save it in said database because of the above conondrums, what should I do?

What I've Thought of Doing So Far

I've tried organizing the data presented to each user using just PHP but seems troublesome, fragile and inefficient.

Should I just create some sort of virtual table system in MySQL just for data handling? Maybe use a good database engine for that purpose?

Maybe I can save all data for each user but have a cron job remove the old data in the database in a constant fashion? Seems troublesome.

The Answer

I'd like some implementation ideas from folks who have encountered a similar problem. I do not care for "try all of the above and see what is faster" type of answers.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: When you scrape it you should format it the way you want it to begin with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is of the *type* you would store in a db and you would benefit from being able to query it in ways that are more difficult in PHP, but you just don't want to *keep* it, you can still use a database. You can create *temporary tables*, insert raw data, and query it to get what you want. When you close the db connection, the tables disappear. Even though the script names them the same, the database will actually create a unique set per connection so each user will have unique data. This solution may not perform as well as you need so do some testing to see if it's suitable for your situation.